# vector in C++ not responding to one method but fine with others

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Probably an ultra-stupid question, but it's late, i'm tired and dinners nearly ready....

Here's a method I have that takes a vector in and assigns the values in it to another vector previously defined as an ivar.
The problem is it throws an error on the last method call saying: No matching member function for call to 'insert'

Here's the code, flame on:

```
void Symbol::setEncodedData( vector<int>* ec )
{
Symbol::encodedSymbol.clear( );
Symbol::encodedSymbol.resize( ec->size( ) );
Symbol::encodedSymbol.insert( 0, ec->begin( ), ec->end( ) );
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Hi, it's the compiler message on building it says: No matching member function for call to 'insert'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Symbol::setEncodedData( vector<int>* ec )
{
    Symbol::encodedSymbol = *ec;
}
```

But why are you using a pointer argument?

```
void Symbol::setEncodedData(vector<int> const& ec)
{
    Symbol::encodedSymbol = ec;
}
```

Comment: It's been a while since I did much C++, usually use Obj-C. I guess my thought was passing a pointer was less overhead than passing by value.
THats what the & in the parameter is right? passing by value? Just want to understand both what I did wrong and what you're code is doing right.

Answer (score 2):

You got your parameters wrong, `0` is not a valid iterator. The possible candidates are:

```
iterator insert ( iterator position, const T& x );
    void insert ( iterator position, size_type n, const T& x );
template <class InputIterator>
    void insert ( iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last );
```

Why not simply use `operator =` to copy the contents?

Comment: re: operator = that was my first thought but it tells me: no viable overloaded '='

Comment: in the last of the example syntax lines, how would you use 'iterator position' to set it to the first element in the vectors underlying array

Comment: @MightyLeader I'm not sure I understand what you mean. What are you trying to achieve? What is `encodedSymbol`?

Comment: Hey Luchian,
encodedSymbol is an instance variable, declared in the .h as a vector of integers.
The method is a constructor.